# Where are defined aliases in Tomcat5

Tags: tomcat

I have an old instance of tomcat5 running on RHEL5.  It serves `http://myserver/RTT` from the files in `/RTT/intranet/build`, assume that means the target of `ant` from the directory `/RTT/intranet`.

In addition, there is an apache server but all the link entered in it are redirected to the Tomcat Server, regardless of the configuration of apache (`Alias /my /home/my`).

Where are located the configuration files?  I found files in `/etc/tomcat` but I cannot grasp how server user port 80 instead of httpd deamon.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the web servers cannot be listening on port 80 simultaneously!

[Apache Tomcat Configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/index.html) is in `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml`.

There you can find, on [HTTP Connectors](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html), the ports Tomcat is listening, e.g. `<Connector port="8080"`.
(That being the default; Tomcat can also use [AJP Connectors](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/ajp.html) that are supported by Apache [mod_proxy_ajp](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html).)

If **Apache** is listening on `80`, you probably have `ProxyPass "/RTT" "http://localhost:8080/bar"` or similar in your Apache configuration, using [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) to forward the requests to Tomcat
   listening on different port.

If **Tomcat** is listening on `80`, Tomcat's equivalent for "aliases" would be [Context](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) containers with attribute `docBase`, like `<Context path="/RTT" docBase="/RTT/intranet/build"`.

---

Please notice that Apache [Tomcat 5.5.x has been EOL](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-55-eol.html) since 30 September 2012 and – even with [RHEL extremely long life cycle](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata) – RHEL5 *Extended Update Support* EUS has ended (depending on the minor release) during years 2010–2015. **Please do not use EOL software.** My answer still applies for currently supported versions, though.

Comment: The Server element does not control the port(s) Tomcat listens on for user agent connections. You should look at the Connector elements for that. In a reverse proxy configuration, httpd may be proxying using the HTTP or AJP protocols. These have different connector configurations but both have a port attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. That part should be corrected now. Since this is a single server environment, I suppose there aren't any Balancer Reverse Proxies involved and `ProxyPass` covers the situation.